# Hassura Container is not connecting to postgres running on localhost

Tags: postgresql, docker

I tried to run Hasura docker container on mac with below command:-

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 \
  -e HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@host.docker.internal:5432/dbname \
  -e HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=true \
  hasura/graphql-engine:latest
```

container exit with below error

```
{"type":"pg-client","timestamp":"2020-06-17T06:09:42.825+0000","level":"warn","detail":{"message":"postgres connection failed, retrying(0)."}}
{"type":"pg-client","timestamp":"2020-06-17T06:09:42.825+0000","level":"warn","detail":{"message":"postgres connection failed, retrying(1)."}}
{"type":"startup","timestamp":"2020-06-17T06:09:42.825+0000","level":"error","detail":{"kind":"db_migrate","info":{"internal":"no connection to the server\n","path":"$","error":"connection error","code":"postgres-error"}}}
```

but initially I got permission related error
user has no permission to create pgcrypto extension by that time it would have connected to Postgres right.

after enabling pgcrypto extension it is not able to connect to Postgres.

Comment: which version of Docker you running on mac? also are you able to connect with Postgres from host with cli? better to verify connection first https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-connect-postgresql-database-command-line

Comment: docker 19.03  yes i am able to connect to postgres on pgAdmin and Cli

Comment: okay then seems like double quotes will work `HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL="postgres://username:password@host.docker.internal:5432/dbname"`

Comment: no it didn't work

Comment: Hi @BharathKumar did you resolve this issue?